# RestTemplate bean is not found in the service layer class even though i have autowired it

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-annotations

When i run the application its working fine but when i build the app its throwing this exception - No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.

below is the code snippet

As a note, i have created this bean in the main application, so its scope is throughout the application but it's still not found. Anyone can offer some help?

```
@Autowired
RestTemplate restTemplateBean;
```

```
@Bean("restTemplateBean")
    public RestTemplate restTemplateBean(RestTemplateBuilder builder) throws IOException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, KeyManagementException {
        SSLContext sslContext = new SSLContextBuilder()
                .loadTrustMaterial(new URL("file:src/main/resources/itsm_qa_api-keystore.jks"), "changeit".toCharArray()).build();

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
                .build();

        return builder
                .requestFactory(() -> new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient))
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: where do you run the application? do you have junit tests?

Comment: Do you get any other error? I'm thinking maybe it doesn't find the path for SSLContext when building...

Comment: Yes, there are junit tests written, Is it failing because of the tests ?. I am able to run application but not able to build it with maven @dcolazin

Comment: You should post the entire stacktrace. Maybe you forgot a test configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As you have defined the specific name for your Bean as `"restTemplateBean"`, when you want to inject that specific bean you need to qualify the bean name as well.

I think you can do it as below:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("restTemplateBean")
RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

Also you can use @Qualifier with combination of constructor injection like this:

```
public class ClassA {

private RestTemplate restTemplate;

public ClassA(@Qualifier("restTemplateBean") RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

}
```

Comment: i have tried that already, but still its not working @Sobhan

Comment: please give it another try and use @component("restTemplateBean") instead of @Bean("restTemplateBean")

Comment: probably you can not do that, sorry!! @Component() is class level, @Bean() is method level, can you convert your method to class?

Comment: i tried to create a component class and write that bean in it, but its not working. I am able to run application but not able to build it with maven @Sobhan

Comment: Also, when i try with this - 
@Inject
RestTemplate restTemplateBean; it builds successfully, but when i run it, restTemplateBean is null

Comment: did you used constructor injection type with combination of @qulifier?, take a look at here:
https://www.studytonight.com/spring-framework/spring-qualifier-with-constructors  , I added it to my answer too

Answer (score 0):

I had forgot to add a bean in Test configuration class, that is why i was getting this exception. Thanks everyone

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).